# VM Exception while processing transaction:Gas estimation errored

Tags: exception, solidity, remix

it is deployed into node by using testrpc it not working in that node especially transferto function and the withdrawal function.how to fix this problem.it's only working in compiler version:0.4.25+commit.59dbf8f1.Emscripten.clang, it's working in higher version of compiler.

Answer (score 0):

It seems code is fine,

Make sure that contract has some ethers on balance `require(address(this).balance >= amount);`

and you calling these functions from owner address `require(msg.sender == _owner);`

If you use solidity version >= 5.0.0, use withdrawal pattern https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/common-patterns.html#withdrawal-pattern

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it could be working in higher versions is because you have constructor() function. If you want to have this contract work for previous versions create the constructor function as function ethertransfer() also when you have revert errors most probably it will happen because the conditions you have written in require() statements. Require Statement also accept second parameter a string which you can put description. Check all require statements carefully, another option I would highly suggest is use remix browser ide. There you can debug through the debug tool in that it will help you step in and step over the transaction flow. So that at the end it will be very easy to identify the root cause of the issue.

Comment: I want to create a dapp, how will deposite function works,in the higher version it showing: Member "transfer" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address.
      receiver.transfer(amount);

Comment: Maybe it will be helpful for you https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/common-patterns.html#withdrawal-pattern